# Can i use user input statement inside switch case statement?

Tags: java

Can i use user input statement inside switch case statement?

This is my code.

```
switch(choice) {
    System.out.println("Enter First Number");
    num1=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Second Number");
    num2=input.nextInt();
    case 1:
        total=num1+num2;
        System.out.println("Addition of "+num1+" and "+num2+" are "+total);
        break;
    case 2:
        total=num1-num2;
        System.out.println("Substraction of "+num1+" and "+num2+" are "+total);
        break;
    case 3:
        total=num1*num2;
        System.out.println("Multiplication of "+num1+" and "+num2+" are "+total);
        break;
    case 4:
        total=num1/num2;
        System.out.println("Divistion of "+num1+" and "+num2+" are "+total);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Please Choose right option...Try again");
        break;

}
```

Is this possible in Java?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Why not simply get the input before the switch statement, and then get it again within a do-while loop if the input is not valid?

Comment: is this not possible inside switch case statement?

Comment: If compiler says you can't do something, the answer is you can't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code won't work as no case is assigned to user input statements...
this thing can be understood by the definition given by oracle
*The body of a switch statement is known as a switch block. **A statement in the switch block can be labeled with one or more case or default labels.** The switch statement evaluates its expression, then executes all statements that follow the matching case label.*
as in your case "the user input statement" are not assigned to any case hence compiler will throw error
but you can take user input, if you put user input statement in any of cases inside switch block
for example:

```
case 1:
System.out.println("Enter First Number");
    num1=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Second Number");
    num2=input.nextInt();
 total=num1+num2;
        System.out.println("Addition of "+num1+" and "+num2+" are "+total);
        break;
```

this will work because now the user input statement are assigned to "case 1" in the switch block...
hope the description  help's you...

Comment: Thanks @anubhav and also thanks for your description

Comment: you are welcome sirif you are satisfied with the answer then you can accept it by clicking the tick button